# informacioncom.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Tags: android, web-services, android-volley

I have a problem when trying to use a PUT method, I am using the PUT method to update my table records through a web service, the problem is that when trying to update the data I get the following error:

> informacioncom.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: End
>   of input at character 0 of

If I checked the table in my database, it does not enter null values, it records blank spaces.

This is my method that iuse for update my data:

```
@Override
    public void onClickUpdate(final int position, final String identificador) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        View MyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin_updatedonante, null);

        final EditText identidad = (EditText)MyView.findViewById(R.id.identificador_tarea);
        final EditText nombre_tarea = (EditText)MyView.findViewById(R.id.nombre_tarea);
        final EditText nota = (EditText)MyView.findViewById(R.id.nota_tarea);
        final EditText estudiante = (EditText)MyView.findViewById(R.id.estudiante_tarea);
        identidad.setEnabled(false);
        identidad.setText(identificador);

        String ntarea = nombre_tarea.getText().toString();
        String not = nota.getText().toString();
        String estudi = estudiante.getText().toString();

        final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try{
            jsonObject.put("nombreUsuario", ntarea)
                    .put("nota", not)
                    .put("estudiante", estudi);
        }catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

        builder.setView(MyView)
                .setPositiveButton("Registrar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        if(nombre_tarea.getText().toString().equals("") || nota.getText().toString().equals("") || estudiante.getText().toString().equals("")){
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Porfavor llena todos los campos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                        }else{
                            String urlPut = "http://192.168.1.81:8080/WebServiceExamenFinal/webapi/tareas/";

                            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.PUT, urlPut + identificador, jsonObject,
                                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Se envió correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ocurrió un error al enviar la información"+error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            });
                            queue.add(request);
                        }
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No se actualizo ningun registro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your jsonObject variable is declared final before you add your data to it. The best solution is to split up your code into separate functions, but for now you could try something like:

```
JSONObject tempJson = new JSONObject();
try{
tempJson.put("nombreUsuario", ntarea)
            .put("nota", not)
            .put("estudiante", estudi);
} catch(JSONException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
final JSONObject jsonObject = tempJson;
```

Comment: I already tried but the error continues, I do not change anything

Comment: Looking at another SO question, it looks like it's possible that the response you're getting back is empty? It might be that when you run the PUT request, the response returned doesn't have a body. 

I would try to run through the code with a debugger or log statements and see what additional information you can find. 

What does the json object look like before it is passed to the volley request?

Referenced question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32104423/volley-jsonexception-end-of-input-at-character-0-of