# How to change a StringRequest into a JsonArrayRequest?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I want to change my `StringRequest` to a `JsonArrayRequest` in order to separate the return into different variables.

As I run this code below:

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Log.d("res", response);
        if (response.equals("failure")) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ungültige Anmeldedaten", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            TV.setText(response);
            //ID = Integer.parseInt(response);
            //switchToMain();
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString().trim(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}){
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("email", email);
        data.put("password", password);
        return data;
    }
};

requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

I return the response:

```
[{"id":"6","Username":"a","Email":"a","Password":"0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661","Status":"Online"}]
```

, which is a JsonArray, isn´t it?

When I try to make a `JsonArrayRequest` I receive errors:

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

JsonArrayRequest queue = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL,null,new Response.Listener<JSONArray>(){
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

        if (response.equals("null")) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ungültige Anmeldedaten", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {

            //ID = Integer.parseInt(response);
            //switchToMain();
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.toString().trim(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}){
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("email", email);
        data.put("password", password);
        return data;
    }
};

requestQueue.add(queue);
```

I receive the following error:

> com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Hello! Seems like it is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32104423/volley-jsonexception-end-of-input-at-character-0-of

Comment: This case is about JsonObjectRequest, are you sure that it is similar with JsonArrayRequest?

Comment: Can you say me where I have to put in that subclass from the similar question?

Comment: Now i added that solution, yeah the program does not crash anymore but as you see the string I get from the reqeuest is not null and now I get response = null